# Using .dae file in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to gazebo and I am going through the tutorials. I want to model a house in gazebo and spawn TurtleBot in it. I downloaded some furniture models in .obj format from http://www.sweethome3d.com/importModels.jsp. Using "Whoola Collada Converter" I converted .obj files to .dae. Now, How to use these .dae file and spawn the furnitures in gazebo ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35819/using-.dae-file-in-gazebo/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2012-06-06**:
@DimitriProsser: Minutes after posting this question, I myself saw that page. I changed the file name to what I had and ran the urdf file in gazebo and rviz. Gazebo said "Model spawned Succesfully" but nothing actually appeared on the window. It was as empty as before. What could be  the problem ?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-06**:
Did you include both the `<visual>` and `<collision>` tags? Are you spawning the model such that it's in collision with the ground or another object? (This could cause it to sink below the ground)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're going to have to build a URDF of your building by following these [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch). In order to use your `.dae` files, you will need to set them as the mesh for `<geometry>`.

```
<link name="left_gripper">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://pr2_description/meshes/gripper_v0/l_finger.dae"/>
    </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3